# css изменение высоты картинки вместе с родительским контейнером

Tags: html, css

**Задача**: размещаю некий блок с высотой к примеру `90vh`, внутри него помещаю изображение, которое по высоте будет меньше родителя. Когда браузер по высоте уменьшается до порога `<=` высоты картинки - картинка также должна адаптивно пропорционально уменьшаться вместе с родительским блоком. Я уменьшаю размер браузера по высоте больше нежели высота изображения - изображение все равно распирает блок (появляется вертикальная прокрутка в браузере). Возможно ли это сделать средствами `CSS`?

```css
.peng {
  width: 376px;
  height: 90vh;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.peng img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="peng">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/879261/58358bb3-ab54-4dbb-a367-6d30108dda74/s1200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение

```
.peng
{
width: 376px;
height: 90vh;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
border: green 1px solid;
}

.peng img
{
width: auto;
max-width: 376px;
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В `CSS` можно воспользоваться методом `object-fit`.

[Имеет 94% поддержку в браузерах](https://caniuse.com/#search=object%20fit) и **не работает в [IE](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/34241747)**

```css
.peng {
  width: 376px;
  height: 90vh;
}

.peng img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: red;
}

.peng.cover img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="peng">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/879261/58358bb3-ab54-4dbb-a367-6d30108dda74/s1200">
</div>

<br />

<div class="peng cover">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/879261/58358bb3-ab54-4dbb-a367-6d30108dda74/s1200">
</div>
```

Comment: Мое решение вроде как валидно во всех браузерах. Но спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.